# Animated show with character that has no legs

Tags: story-identification, tv

I can vaguely remember watching this show in the late 80s or possibly the early 90s.  It was a fantasy setting in which a man and a group or mutants or aliens were traveling together.  The only concrete memory I have is that one of the characters had no lower body and got around on just his arms.  I'm not sure if it was a movie or series and it may have been on pay cable and may have contained nudity.

In my searching the only thing I found was a post on Yahoo answers from a girl looking for possibly the same thing.  She adds: "the man and group of aliens are watching, from a distance, this dinosaur nest of eggs. One of the eggs begins to move. A little later a woman hatches from the egg."

Comment: Could have sworn there was a character like that on Freak Show (a Comedy Channel cartoon), but Wikipedia disagrees and the timeframe is wrong (mid-2000s).

Comment: Im not sure but you might be referring to one of the parts to the Heavy Metal movie: "Taarna". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_%28film%29

Comment: Talking about nudity and stuff... sounds like Heavy Metal. Although would be useful if you remember whether it's been drawn or live-action/mixed?

Comment: It was definitely all animation and it wasn't Heavy Metal.  

A friend suggested Gandahar(Light Years).  I'm watching it now.  It certainly fits the bill, but totally doesn't ring any bells so far.  I'm thinking it must be it though, mutants, no leg dude, and nudity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you're thinking of [Gandahar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandahar_%28film%29)?

Check out Fig 5 on [this review](http://isaacbickerstaff.wordpress.com/2010/02/06/on-gandahar-light-years/) - is the guy on the far right the one you're thinking of?